# nv-websocket-client self-signed certificate

Tags: android, websocket, self-signed

I am trying to connect to a WSS server on my intranet with a self signed certificate. I have used Volley for HTTPS and TooTallNate library for WSS and I have been able to set SSLContext to accept all certificates. I am currently switching to nv-websocket-client so that I can add custom headers but, for the love of god, cant seem to bypass SSL certificate verification. I continue to run into the error message "The certificate of the peer...does not match the expected hostname". The code is exactly what is in the docs? is something different in v2.2? Here is the code I am using,

```
SSLContext context = NaiveSSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

ws = new WebSocketFactory().setSSLContext(context).setConnectionTimeout(5000)
            .createSocket("wss://192.168.1.164/chat/")
            .addListener(new WebSocketAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onTextMessage(WebSocket websocket, String message) {
                    // Received a text message.
                   }
                @Override
                public void onConnectError(WebSocket websocket, WebSocketException e){
                    mTextView.setText(e.getMessage());
                }
            });
ws.connectAsynchronously();`
```

Can somebody help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The author for the package has addressed it as an issue with a new feature in v2.3

```
WebSocketFactory.setVerifyHostname(false)
```

https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client/issues/116